# How to tell when ExternalInterface is available when hiding and showing a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

I've got a swf with some js callbacks registered using ExternalInterface. I hide and show the swf repeatedly, and I've learned that ExternalInterface is not available when the swf is hidden. I also noticed that the swfs constructor is called every time it shows again, which I've used to make sure I don't try to call an ExternalInterface function before its available. This makes me wonder though if there is also some way to reliably tell from inside the swf when it is hidden? I know as3 classes don't have destructors, but is there anything similar that could be used to fire an ExternalInterface event right before the swf becomes unavailable again? REMOVED_FROM_STAGE doesn't seem to help out with detecting this as it doesn't fire at all.

I'm using several methods of hiding and showing btw. Sometimes using angular's ng-hide/ng-show and sometimes the swf is within a bootstrap modal window.

Also, I've noticed Flash Builder can somehow tell when the swf unloads. I can add a button that sets 'display: none' on the embedded `<object>` and I get the [Unload SWF] message in the console in Flash Builder. Is this just a feature of the debug player, or is there some secret event Flash Builder knows of that I have yet to find?

Comment: Hmm, good question. As a workaround, you could always manually send an event from JS to the SWF before hiding it.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it seems that it's completely unloading the swf. So it's not that ExternalInterface is unavailable it's that the swf is not running/loaded at all anymore.  What browser are you using?  Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: I'm in chrome, and I'm literally just doing flashPlayer.style.display = 'none'; and thats unloading the swf immediately.

Comment: Well, there are several ways to hide your SWF app. You can display:none it, or set visibility:hidden. You can also use absolute pisitioning and move it out of screen. In last case you should also look at hasPriority parameter for your SWF. But I recommend you to look at two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610976/how-to-stop-swf-inside-of-a-jquery-ui-tab-from-reloading and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587087/stop-reloading-flash-file-when-using-show-and-hide-methods

Comment: Yes, currently working around this with the absolute position off-screen method. Forgot to update, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list available callbacks exposed by a flash element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047810/how-to-list-available-callbacks-exposed-by-a-flash-element)

Comment: Its very good question. making absolute position and moving out it from screen is one good workaround and there is surety for proper execution. But you can do make layer using jQuery and you can put swf in lower layer and to hide just overlap with another layer of the jQuery UI.

Comment: Have you explored the throttling event to determine if the swf is being throttled when hidden?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to check if a SWF can call ExternalInterface:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log","hello browser");
}
```